# Does Central Admin Export List affect the source list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I exported a list using the central admin facility and it seems the personal views on the list were deleted? Is this a result of the export? Are there any other side effects?

Comment: personal views for which id?

Comment: Some of my users reported loosing their personal views on the source list after I exported.

Answer (score 3):

Exporting a SharePoint list doesn't change the source at all. Make sure you're accessing the list with the same account you created the view with, since you may have created a personal instead of public view.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally strange, because exporting the a list/site will not hurt anything at source list /site. Only time it hurts is when you export / backup the whole site collections then some time it put the lock on the site collections.

I am sure you are talking about the source list not the Targeted List(after import). I would check the ULS logs during the export process and see if we get some clue why personal views are disappeared.

Comment: Strange part is the person affected is the owner of the list. I'm thinking that maybe the act of locking down the site caused the personal view to drop, but I can't think what would do that.

Comment: But their is no way to lock the list....I would go for logs to get some clue...did u import that exported list somewhere or no, or stuck with this issue after restore....I am thinking may be u looking wrong list

Comment: Yes, I subsequently imported it into a new site collection. Would that affect the original list?

Comment: No, but I wana make sure u r accessing the right list...source list not the imported list